# list of 3rd party apps installed on all sites

Tags: sharepoint-online

Anyone know how we can get a list of all 3rd party app installed on sites in a tenant?
Get-pnpapp just seems to only show thinks in my app catalog.
Russell

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Get-SPOAppInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/get-spoappinfo?view=sharepoint-ps).

**Description**

The Get-SPOAppInfo cmdlet gets all the installed applications from an external marketplace or from the App Catalog that contain Name in their application names or the installed application with mentioned ProductId. ProductId takes precedence if not empty.

Use this command:

```
Get-SPOAppInfo -Name " " | Sort Name
```